# SQL template on azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to migrate my mysql 5.6 DB to sql server.

Trying to decide wether I should use Azure "SQL Database" as an instance, or should I create a VM with SQL SERVER installed.

This is the SQL database I can create using azure services:

[image]

Or use one of these virtual machines:

[image]

any tips ?

Comment: Can you provide some context and an idea of what you're trying to achieve. There are plenty of documents that discuss the differences, tell us what is important to you and we will try to help you find the most applicable solution to YOUR situation. But we need to know your problem  first.

Comment: Topic edited @MichaelB

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL would save you from the hassle of managing everything by yourself compared to the IaaS, SQL Server VM. However, this comes with tradeoffs like size limitation, sharding limitations etc. I think you'd appreciate a table comparison of the two to decide. Kindly find below [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-management-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-iaas/) for a comparison of the two in terms of both business motivation and limitations.

Hope this helps!

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-management-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-iaas/